# Regex - remove four special characters between [image=][/image] BB tag

Tags: php, regex

In a script I have a BB-image code that can have one of these two formats:

```
[image=http://i459.photobucket.com/albums/xxx/enkidu-wd/test/38602_450pom.jpg][/image] (without Alt text)

[image=https://m.photobucket.com/enkidu-wd/test/38602_450pomnik.jpg]alt text[/image] (with Alt text)
```

My goal is to always remove these four characters: `$ & ' "` - but ONLY IF these characters are added as the alt text (ie. between the `[image=...]ALT TEXT[/image]`). If these characters appear anywhere outside of the `[image][/image]` tags in the $text message, they should be ignored (not removed).

I tried to use preg_replace as below, but it doesn't work.. Note that $text is a message that may or may not include this [image][/image] tag.

```
$start = '\[image=';
$end  = '\[\/image\]';
$text = preg_replace(
    '#('.$start.')(.*)('.$end.')#i',
    '$1'.str_replace(array('$','&','\'','"'),'').(*).'$3',
    $text
);
```

Comment: what is the reason behind removing the characters? i would think a better practice would be to sanitize them as you might otherwise corrupt the users original intent.

Comment: The reason is 'security', ie. when user enters one of these characters, BB-code image doesn't work.. not sure why but it's a 3rd party script.. they say it's for security..

Comment: ah, well. if that's their excuse `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Tom please try my library Shortcode for parsing shortcodes https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A)|[image\b[^]]*])[^[$&\'"]*\K[$&\'"]~i';
```

if other BBCODE tags can be included between image tags, you can change it like this:

```
$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A)|[image\b[^]]*])[^[$&\'"]*(?:\[(?!/image\b)[^][]*][^[$&\'"]*)*\K[$&\'"]~i';
```

use:

```
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $yourstring);
```

details:

```
~ # pattern delimiter
(?:
    \G(?!\A) # contiguous to the previous match, not at the start of the string
  | # OR
    [image\b[^]]*] # an opening image tag
)
[^[$&\'"]* #"# all that isn't an opening square bracket or one the chars
\K # remove all that has been matched before from the match result
[$&\'"]
~i
```

Explanation:

Since `[^[$&\'"]*` forbids an opening square bracket, once the closing `[/image]` is reached, the contiguity is broken and the `\G` anchor fails. The only way to continue is to find an other opening `[image...]` tag.

Comment: Sorry - what if I also wanted to remove: [] from the alt text, what should I add? I tried: $pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A)|[image\b[^]]*])[^[[]$&\'"]*\K[$&\'"]~i'; but it doesn't work?

Comment: @Tom: take the first pattern and change `[^[$&\'"]*\K[$&\'"]` to `[^][$&\'"]*\K(?:[]$&\'"]|\[(?!/image\b))` (inside a character class in pcre, if you don't want to escape the closing square bracket `]`, put it at the beginning of the class or after the negation `^`)

Comment: OK so it should be:?

$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A)|[image\b[^]]*])[^][$&\'"]*\K(?:[]$&\'"]|\[(?!/image\b))~i';

Comment: Perhaps, but I can't really see since you don't use formatting (put grave accents around code)

Comment: `$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A)|[image\b[^]]*])[^][$&\'"]*\K(?:[]$&\'"]|[(‌​?!/image\b))~i';` - this one :)?

Comment: @Tom: you forget to escape literal opening brackets: `$pattern = '~(?:\G(?!\A)|\[image\b[^]]*])[^][$&\'"]*\K(?:[]$&\'"]|\[(‌​?!‌​/image\b))~i';`

Comment: The issue - when I used it like below, it shows warning: "PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (? or (?- at offset"


`$text = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\[image\b[^]]*])[^][$&\'"]*\K(?:[]$&\'"]|\[(?????!??/image\b))~i','',$text);`

Comment: Hm, the likely issue was when copy-pasting this code, extra spaces/question marks are added for some reason, when manually entering it seems to work well : )